# Is there a way to omit the leading slash in react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm attempting to migrate an application from a custom library to react/redux.  I'm investigating using react-router as our top-level routing tool.

I'm planning on using `hashHistory` as our existing route tree is done entirely in hashes.  However, our existing route tree does not include a leading slash after the `#`.

In order to not break all our existing links, I'm wondering if there is a way to omit the leading slash.

So far, I've attempted:

```
import {createHashHistory} from 'history'

const custom_history = useRouterHistory(createHashHistory)({
  hashType: 'noslash'
})

class Router extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router history={custom_history}>
        <Route path="" component={Container}>
           <Route path="dashboard" component={SubContainer} />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

But using `createHashHistory` directly from the `history` library appears to cause an error in the second nested `getCurrentLocation` call of `history.listen`.

Is there a means to do this in react-router ^3.0.0?

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: @PaulS That `history.getCurrentLocation` is not a function.  I'm using `react-router ^3.0.0` and `history ^4.4.1` as the two referenced libraries in the example.

Comment: history v4 is for use with react router v4. Try using history@3.2.1